Microsoft Community Toolkit for Maui - ImageTouchBehavior
I have a ListView with an Image that I have added the Behavior
<Image.Behaviors>
  <mct:ImageTouchBehavior                     
   LongPressCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference ImageListView}, 
       Path=BindingContext.MyLongPressCommand}"
   />
</Image.Behaviors>

I can get it to fire off the Command, but I need to pass it a Parameter so I can tell what the LongPress was.
I have tried the LongPressCommandParameter but because the behavior doesn't let you just specify a {Binding myproperty}, I cannot use this LongPressCommand to determine what was pressed.
Anyone have this working?
